# How to combine MTLTextures into the currentDrawable

Tags: ios, swift, metal

I am new to using Metal but I have been following the tutorial [here](https://navoshta.com/metal-camera-part-1-camera-session/) that takes the camera output and renders it on to the screen using metal.

Now I want to take an image, turn it into a MTLTexture, and position and render that texture on top of the camera output.

My current rendering code is as follows:

```
private func render(texture: MTLTexture, withCommandBuffer commandBuffer: MTLCommandBuffer, device: MTLDevice) {
    guard
        let currentRenderPassDescriptor = metalView.currentRenderPassDescriptor,
        let currentDrawable = metalView.currentDrawable,
        let renderPipelineState = renderPipelineState,
        let encoder = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: currentRenderPassDescriptor)
    else {
        semaphore.signal()
        return
    }
    
    encoder.pushDebugGroup("RenderFrame")
    encoder.setRenderPipelineState(renderPipelineState)
    encoder.setFragmentTexture(texture, index: 0)
    encoder.drawPrimitives(type: .triangleStrip, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: 4, instanceCount: 1)
    encoder.popDebugGroup()
    encoder.endEncoding()
    
    commandBuffer.addScheduledHandler { [weak self] (buffer) in
        guard let unwrappedSelf = self else { return }
        
        unwrappedSelf.didRenderTexture(texture, withCommandBuffer: buffer, device: device)
        unwrappedSelf.semaphore.signal()
    }

    commandBuffer.present(currentDrawable)
    commandBuffer.commit()
}
```

I know that I can convert a `UIImage` to a MTLTexture using the following code:

```
let textureLoader = MTKTextureLoader(device: device)
let cgImage = UIImage(named: "myImage")!.cgImage!
let imageTexture = try! textureLoader.newTexture(cgImage: cgImage, options: nil)
```

So now I have two `MTLTextures`. Is there a simple function that allows me to combine them? I've been trying to search online and someone mentioned a function called `over`, but I haven't actually been able to find that one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this inside the shader by adding or multiplying color values. I guess that's what shaders are for.